# Combine Three DataFrames Using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to combine three pandas DataFrames in python. Below are the three DataFrames that I am trying to combine as well as my desired output (where NaN is null). I know that joining the two tables with a left merge did not work. What is the correct sequence of two merges to achieve the desired output? (Does not have to be one line of code if it is not possible) Thanks!

```
df1
    +--------+
    | x      |
    +--------+
    | 1      |
    | 2      |
    | 3      |
    +--------+

df2
    +--------+---+
    | x      | b |
    +--------+---+
    | 1      | A |
    | 1      | B |
    | 1      | C |
    | 2      | D |
    | 2      | E |
    | 2      | F |
    | 3      | G |
    +--------+---+

df3
    +--------+---+
    | x      | c |
    +--------+---+
    | 1      | L |
    | 1      | M |
    | 2      | N |
    | 3      | O |
    | 3      | P |
    | 3      | Q |
    +--------+---+

df_result
    +----------------+-----+-----+
    | x              |  b  |  c  |
    +----------------+-----+-----+
    | 1              | A   | NaN |
    | 1              | B   | NaN |
    | 1              | C   | NaN |
    | 1              | NaN | L   |
    | 1              | NaN | M   |
    | 2              | D   | NaN |
    | 2              | E   | NaN |
    | 2              | F   | NaN |
    | 2              | NaN | N   |
    | 3              | G   | NaN |
    | 3              | NaN | O   |
    | 3              | NaN | P   |
    | 3              | NaN | Q   |
    +----------------+-----+-----+
```

The following attempts do not result in the the df_result DataFrame as shown above:

```
attempt1:
df_step1 = df1.merge(df2, on='x', how='left')
df_result = df_step1.merge(df3, on='x', how='left')
df_result
```

I have tried the above with a varying combination of left, right, outer and inner joins / merges

```
attempt2:
df_result = pd.concat([table1, table2, table3], axis=1, sort='false')
df_result
```

This also does not produce the desired df_result DataFrame.

Perhaps I need a combination of a concat and merge? Or, because it is a new row for each entry basically, I could just write a for loop that enters the information for each of these entries in a new series in the df. Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(df1.index)):
        for j in range (len(df2.index)):
            df_result = df_result.append(df2[j])

        for k in range (len(df3.index)):
            df_result = df_result.append(df3[k])
```

Comment: where is O from Table 2

Comment: And why is "x" the only value that only gets 1 row and not 2? Or, is "x", "b", and "c" column names?

Comment: I suppose you want an analogue to [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/comparison_with_sql.html#full-join), aren't you?

Comment: Hmm, is `pd.concat([df1, df2])` what you want?

Comment: @coldspeed yes. I did not paste the tables correctly so the formatting in the post is off. The first row should be the column names. I will edit the original post.

Comment: @Wen-Ben I added O from Table 2. My mistake.

Comment: @AlexYu unfortunately just using pd.concat for all three (or even two) of the frames will not work. Using `df_step1 = df1.merge(df2, on='x', how='left')` works for the first step, but does not get me all the way there.

Comment: Add some code to your question. Use [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Comment: @AlexYu I added some more code to demonstrate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 'A'),
 (1, 'B'),
 (1, 'C'),
 (2, 'D'),
 (2, 'E'),
 (3, 'F'),
 (3, 'G')], columns = ("x","b"))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 'L'),
 (1, 'M'),
 (2, 'N'),
 (3, 'L'),
 (3, 'O'),
 (3, 'P'),
 (3, 'Q')], columns= ("x","c"))

df2["c"] = float('nan')
df3["b"] = float('nan')

df_result=pd.concat((df2,df3), sort=True)[["x","b","c"]]
df_result.sort_values("x")
```

I got:

```
   x     b     c
0  1    A  NaN
1  1    B  NaN
2  1    C  NaN
0  1  NaN    L
1  1  NaN    M
3  2    D  NaN
4  2    E  NaN
2  2  NaN    N
5  3    F  NaN
6  3    G  NaN
3  3  NaN    L
4  3  NaN    O
5  3  NaN    P
6  3  NaN    Q
```

Comment: Aha! Yes! Thank you. This solves it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found that concatenating the second and third dataframes, and then after that, sorting by the `x` column allowed me to produce a df that matches the expected output defined above in `df_result`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                    'b': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,2,3,3,3],
                    'c': ['L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']})


pd.concat([df2, df3], sort=False).sort_values('x').set_index('x', drop=True)

    b   c
x       
1   A   NaN
1   B   NaN
1   C   NaN
1   NaN L
1   NaN M
2   D   NaN
2   E   NaN
2   F   NaN
2   NaN N
3   G   NaN
3   NaN O
3   NaN P
3   NaN Q
```